# Regex to match exact number

Tags: regex

I have a lot of LOC of a project in visual studio and I want to search for every line which uses the numbers 12 and 13. It can't be part of a bigger number, I need to retrieve only the code that actually uses the constants 12 and 13. I think it is possible to do with regex but I'm having a hard time here.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you made any attempt whatsoever? `1[23]` BTW.

Comment: `Edit -> Find and Replace -> Find in Files` then use `\b1[23]\b`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP hasn't done any effort. This is not a "gimme some code" website. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Guys I did try, using "1[23]" will not give what I ask for. As I stated in the question "It can't be part of a bigger number, I need to retrieve only the code that actually uses the constants 12 and 13." Using 1[23] will give me any results that have the number 12 or 13 anywhere in the line. I need only the code that uses exactly the numbers 12 or 13, not 122 or 1513. I did google but didnt find nothing objective about this specific scenario.

Comment: @underthevoid you should [**Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But anyway, what I posted above  seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @ctwheels your regex indeed works as I needed, I didn't see it in middle of such rage in these comments, sorry for that. If you want to answer the topic I'll accept, if not I will answer and quote you. Thanks.

Comment: @underthevoid I added my answer with an explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Brief

You want to use the `Find and Replace` window found at `Edit -> Find and Replace -> Find in Files` with the regex `\b1[23]\b` and the `Find Options` `Use Regular Expressions` checkbox selected.

[image: Find and Replace box]

---

### Code

- `\b` Word boundary assertion

  - Matches, without consuming any characters, immediately between a character matched by `\w` and a character not matched by `\w` (in either order). It cannot be used to separate non-words from words.
- `1` Match this literally
- `[23]` Match a character in the set (`2` or `3`)
- `\b` Word boundary assertion

Comment: Very appreciated @ctwheels

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<![0-9])1[23](?![0-9])
```

Will match

```
12
13
abc12hbd
```

but not

```
3456324123656
234564567546
121212
13121312
1
3
123
```

If your 12 or 13 might appear in a hexadecimal string you can exclude that with

```
(?<![0-9a-fA-F])1[23](?![0-9a-fA-F])
```

You need to decide what characters are allowed to be on either side of the 12 or 13 and then exclude the others. See https://regex101.com/ for more help

Comment: Thanks for answering but the regex you gave returns lines where the numbers "12" and "13" are in middle of a bigger number (e.g "static int (*BASE_GetItemAmount)(STRUCT_ITEM* item)        = (int (__cdecl*)(STRUCT_ITEM*)) 0x4013D9;" this line triggers the regex by the number "0x4013D9"). Any idea why?

Comment: @underthevoid
I've made an update but you should also try to understand the regex and change it to suit your own needs

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution:

```
 ^\D*(?<p>12|13)\D*
```

the group with the name p would hold the 12 or 13.
But you better try to use an online regex tester such as https://regex101.com/ or any other that shows up on google.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the when I tested here your regex returned some lines of code that even have any number (e.g "fclose(out);"). The lines that had numbers seems to work fine though.

Comment: It might be that visual studio does not support the D for pattern matching a small d would be any number.